# User page is displaying "funny"

Tags: bug, status-completed

I've seen the below on the users page a few times in the last day. If I'm remembering correctly it was consistantly the top 3 or four users in the third column. It looks like the top 3 display over the next bottom 3. Although that is not consistant. I've also seen it where just one of the users was over another user several spaces down.
 [image]

I was working on an XP box using IE8. I don't think I've seen it on my Win7 box, also running IE8 but I can't say that for sure. I do not see this every time but probably over half the times (maybe 4 or 5 times total).

This has now happened on my Win7 box with IE8 too.
[image]

Comment: What's your environment? Please provide a full description. No-repro here.

Comment: Possibly migrate to MSO?

Comment: I have now seen this on Programmers.SE as well... this should be migrated to MSO.

Comment: It _IS_ on MSO already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39353/problem-with-user-list-page

Comment: Interesting, that one is marked as a duplicate but the link goes to a page not found. Looks like the original question was deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we've seen this before. This is clearly a totally non-reproducible bug in IE8 (I've actually seen it fix itself if you just wait long enough).

However, I *think* I've found a workaround for this bug. Of course, with non-reproducible bug [you can never be sure](http://www.dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif), but the bug didn't reappear even after a lot of clicking, so I guess it works.

This will be live in the next build.